# File path disappears when logged in

Tags: ee2, members, files

I created a simple member's area, where people can login and download PDFs.

When I created the new member group, create a new member, and login as them – **all** file paths are disappearing on the front-end, meaning while the new member's login session is active, no path links are displaying when viewing the site/templates, in any sections. All other tags are coming out as normal.

The original paths are in a file field in a Matrix row – but I also created a basic file field to test (native), but still it is not showing paths.

I can't seem to find any occurrences or similar problems to this.

When I am logged in as Super Admin all is working as expected, it is **only** when I login as a member from this new member group, file paths disappear on front end.

I'm on EE v 2.5.3.

Thanks in advance!
Glen

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions issue with your upload folders. Make sure in file manager > file upload preferences  that your new member group has access.